# Something simple I'm missing here (iterating lists)

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need this list to append a list for each line in a file, then to sort the output. It takes input from a file (numbers.txt). I've tried everything I can think of to get it to sort; finally I've made some 'progress' but newlist2 here only returns none and newlist isn't sorted. What am I doing wrong?

```
import sys
import os


print("\n && ************************************************ &&\n && Welcome to the text document average calculator! && \n && ************************************************ &&\n\n Please ensure your file contains only numeric charactesr! \n By default, the program will look for a document named 'numbers' in this folder.")




def averager():
    
####Declarations     
    count = int(0)
    sunn = int(0)
    target = str('')
    beginbool = bool(False)
    
####Statement
    try:
        while beginbool == False:
            specify = input(" Specify directory? Y / N: ")
            if any(specify.lower() == f for f in ['y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'YES', 'YEs', 'yES', 'yEs', 'yeS']):
                rngfile = open(input('Please input file location: '), 'r')
                beginbool == True
                break
            elif any(specify.lower() == f for f in ['N', 'n', 'No', 'no', 'nO', 'NO']):
                rngfile = open("numbers.txt", 'r')
                beginbool == True
                break
            else:
                print('Please input yes, no, or something close at least...')
                pass
            
####User Data
        print('\n&&***********************************&&')
        print("&& Line:        LiVal:        Sum:   &&\n&&***********************************&&")

####For loop
        for line in rngfile:
            iteration = int(line)
            truelist = list([])
            truelist.append(int(iteration))
            count += 1
            sunn += iteration
            if sunn == 0 and count == 0:
                print("Empty list detected.")
            elif sunn != 0 and count != 0:
                newlist = [int(x) for x in truelist]
                newlist.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
                newlist2 = newlist.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
                print(sorted(newlist))
                print(newlist2)
                pass
            else:
                pass
            

####Close
        rngfile.close()

####Exceptions

    except IOError:
        print("Error reading the file.")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Divided by zero? (This usually happens when the filename is incorrect, or the file is empty.)")

        
####Display Average
    average = (sunn / count)



####User Data
    print('&&***********************************&& \n\n The numerical average of the file is: ', average)
    print(' Thank you for using the numerical averager!')


    


####Run        
averager()

####Finish
input("\n Press any key to exit.") 
sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Though this is unrelated to your question, `any(specify.lower() == f for f in ['y', 'Y', 'Yes', 'YES', 'YEs', 'yES', 'yEs', 'yeS'])` is very clumsy; for starters, `specify.lower()` makes the entry lowercase, so it will never be equal to, say, 'Y'; you can replace all this with `specify.lower() in [ 'y', 'yes']`; also `break` breaks out of the `while` loop, so your `beginbool` flag is useless; finally, `int(0)` is unnecessary, since `0` is already an int. Strive not to uselessly lengthen your code, for shorter code is easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

`.sort()` method is sorting list in-place, it always returns None

so in the line:

```
newlist2 = newlist.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
```

You are assign None to the newlist2 variable, consider using [`sorted`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_sorted.asp) function:

```
newlist2 = sorted(newlist, key=int, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Using Sorted instead returns the unsorted set of values.

Comment: @reunion please try it like this: `newlist2 = sorted(newlist, key=int, reverse=True)`, Does it still return the unsorted set?

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
        for line in rngfile:
            ...
            truelist = list([])
            truelist.append(int(iteration))
```

That doesn't look right.
You ensure it has zero lines, then you append a line.

Didn't you want to initialize `truelist` *before*
starting the `for` loop?

---

You wrote

```
                newlist.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
                newlist2 = newlist.sort(key=int, reverse=True)
```

Again, that doesn't look right.
The `.sort()` return value will always be `None`.

I recommend you avoid `.sort()`, and prefer `sorted()`.
It is more modern and [offers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) a far more
convenient interface, handing back a new list each time.
It supports the same options, e.g. `key=` and `reverse=`.

Comment: I moved it to my declarations, same effect.

Comment: Okay, a combination of these two fixes actually did the trick. Thank you so so much kind sir (and everyone else too).